# DIVs will not render past browser viewport but text will

Tags: html, css

[http://jsfiddle.net/Dmb7v/ :](http://jsfiddle.net/Dmb7v/1/)

```
<body>
<div class="Shell">
    <div class="Main">
        <div class="Header">
        <p>Name Surname</p>
        <p>G123456789</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Content">
        <p>VIEW NAVIGATION</p>
            <ul>
            <li>Menu Item 1</li>
            <li>Menu Item 2</li>
            <li>Menu Item 3</li>
            <li>Menu Item 4</li>
            <li>Menu Item 5</li>
            <li>Menu Item 6</li>
            <li>Menu Item 7</li>
            <li>Menu Item 8</li>
            <li>Menu Item 9</li>
            <li>Menu Item 10</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Pane">
        <div>
            <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2711/free_icons_for_windows8_metro/128/beer.png" height="48px" width="48px">
        </div>
        <div>
        <span class="PaneText">My Team's Requests / Managed by my direct reports / Processes Completed / Processes Completed / Processes Completed / Processes Completed</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin : 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.Shell {
    height: 100%;
}

.Main {
    width: 332px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffcccc;
    border: 2px solid red;
    float: left;
}

.Header {
    width: 332px;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: #ccccff;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

.Content {
    width: 332px;
    background-color: #ccffcc;
    border: 2px solid green;
}

.Pane {
    height: 100%;
    width: 48px;
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    overflow: visible;
    float: left;
}

.PaneText {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    font-size: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 48px;
}
```

I've built a very basic menu on the left side of the screen. I will have text vertically run down the right side of the menu. The text is rendered in full but the DIV it's inside will not.

What am I doing wrong? I've found all sorts of suggestions but none work. Suggestions such as this:

```
html, body {
min-height:100%;  
height:auto;  
height:100%;
}
```

None of them worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Of course this happens, when you set a height of 100%, and the content of the element exceed that …

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. I was wondering how I could get the DIV to extend as far the text.

Comment: Only by _not_ giving it a `height`, but only a `min-height`.

Comment: Hmm I gave the "Pane" class a `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` and still have the same problem. Have I mis-interpreted?

Comment: I thought this was about your menu? That is not in `.pane` as far as I can infer from your code.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. I meant the background colours of all the DIVs stop rendering once they hit the bottom of the viewport. The vertical text is rendered though. I'd like all the divs to render as far down as the text goes. Apologies again.

Comment: _“I meant the background colours of all the DIVs stop rendering once they hit the bottom of the viewport”_ – and again, that happens when you give them a height and the content exceeds that height. _“I'd like all the divs to render as far down as the text goes.”_ – again, then _don’t_ give them a height that might be exceeded by the content.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks very much. My problem is not with `height`. It's with positioning the `.Pane` flush with the menu once it's been transformed 90deg. Cheers.